# TipTap React: Update Editor Initial Content based on dropdown selection

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tiptap

I'm using TipTap as the rich text editor for my react project for updating the description of the product which has been selected from the dropdown.

The expected outcome is that the editor should show the initial content which has been saved in the database for the respective product.

However, using the 'content' option in editor allows me to set the initial content, it does not updates the initial content if i change the option in dropdown.

[image: update data]

**My Editor Code:**

```
import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/react';
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit';
import Underline from '@tiptap/extension-underline';
import Placeholder from '@tiptap/extension-placeholder';
import TipTapMenubar from './TipTapMenubar';

const TiptapEditor = ({ description, setDescription }) => {
  // console.log('description', description);

  const sampleDesc = `Describe your product in 4-5 bullet points...
    Point #1: this is an explanation of my product.
    Point #2: ....`;

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      StarterKit,
      Underline,
      Placeholder.configure({
        placeholder: sampleDesc,
      }),
    ],
    content: `${description}`,
    onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
      const html = editor.getHTML();
      setDescription(html);
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className='!mt-2 border border-gray-300 shadow rounded'>
      <TipTapMenubar editor={editor} />
      <EditorContent editor={editor} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TiptapEditor;
```

**This Editor component is then called in a parent component to display the data:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import TiptapEditor from '@/components/common/editor/TiptapEditor';
import InputInlineLabel from '@/components/form/InputInlineLabel';
import LoadingButton from '@/components/form/LoadingButton';

function ProductOptionNameDesc({
  product,
  selectedOption,
  name,
  setName,
  description,
  setDescription,
  loading,
  handleProductOptionData,
  handleProductOptionsDescription,
}) {
  const [enableEditor, setEnableEditor] = useState(false);
  // console.log('product', product);
  // console.log('selectedOption', selectedOption);
  // if selectedOption, set name and description from it
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption) {
      const productOptions = product?.product_options;
      productOptions?.map((option) => {
        if (option?.id === selectedOption?.id) {
          setName(option?.name);
          setDescription(option?.description);
        }
      });
      setEnableEditor(true);
    }
  }, [selectedOption]);

  // console.log('description', description);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleProductOptionData}>
        <div className='space-y-4'>
          <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
            <label htmlFor='poname' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
              Product option name
            </label>
            <input
              id='poname'
              name='poname'
              placeholder='product name'
              className='w-full rounded p-2 border border-gray-300 text-sm placeholder:text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-purple-500'
              value={name || ''}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='space-y-2'>
            {enableEditor ? (
              <TiptapEditor
                description={description}
                setDescription={setDescription}
                placeholder='Add up to 5 points describing the product...'
              />
            ) : (
              <div>
                <Skeleton height={20} />
                <Skeleton height={70} />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>

            {loading ? (
              <LoadingButton />
            ) : (
              <button className='text-sm w-full py-1 px-2 rounded cursor-pointer border border-violet-700 bg-violet-50 hover:bg-violet-100 text-violet-700'>
                Update name and description
              </button>
            )}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductOptionNameDesc;
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If a user selects the color brown in dropdown and there is already some initial value saved for the same in database for brown, then the useEffect hook updates the description state, however, it is not reflected in the tiptap editor content.

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://tiptap.dev/api/commands/set-content

Answer (score 8):

Check if this helps: add description variable to dependency array of useEditor

```
 const editor = useEditor({
    ...
 },[description]);
```

Comment: oh wow, this is a good one, I didn't realize `useEditor` is actually a React hook and you can pass the state. Thanks that worked for me!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is an issue, When I try to edit the content the focus goes out every time I use a spacebar or any keypress.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably want to run the effect inside of the Editor component to use the `setContent` function referenced in a comment above.

This would look something like

```js
  const editor = useEditor({
    ...
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    editor.commands.setContent(description);
  }, [description]);
```

Re-rendering the editor by adding `description` as a dependency may work but is 1) more expensive, 2) may not appear precisely as you'd like and 3) doesn't trigger `onTransaction` or any of TipTap's callbacks or state changes that you may depend on in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `editor?.commands.setContent(description)` works well, but it may cause some inconsistencies. In my case, the space is not working and the cursor moves to the end of the editor content. So better add a check before setting the content-

```js
  const editor = useEditor({
    ...
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editor?.isEmpty && description !== '<p></p>') {
        editor.commands.setContent(description);
    }
  }, [description]);
```

Here you will set the content once the editor is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
// useRef hook to track if the initial content has been set
const valueRendered = useRef(false);

// useEffect hook to set the initial content in the editor
useEffect(() => {
  // Ensure the editor instance exists and has not been destroyed
  if (editor && !editor.isDestroyed) {
    // Check if there's a value to set and if it hasn't been set already
    if (value && !valueRendered.current) {
      // Set the editor content using the provided value
      editor?.commands?.setContent(value);

      // Update the flag to prevent setting the content multiple times
      valueRendered.current = true;
    }
  }
}, [editor, value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controlled component with form(I'm using react hook form), following solution is working for me. It' not my answer. I got it from this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/2216#issuecomment-1098232339)

```
const editor = useEditor({
extensions: [ StarterKit,
 content: content|| "",
onUpdate({ editor }) {
  const value = editor.getHTML();
  onChange(value);
},});

useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor) return;
    let {from, to} = editor.state.selection;
    editor.commands.setContent(content,
        false, {
            preserveWhitespace: "full"
        });
    editor.commands.setTextSelection({from, to});
}, [editor, content]);

return (
<div>
  <EditorToolbar editor={editor} />
  <EditorContent editor={editor} />
</div> );
```

***If you have better or more optimized solution, Please share with us.***